# Why is my SliverAppBar not responding at all?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to implement a sliver app bar in my flutter app but it just won't respond at all

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 200,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text("title"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you point the issue, what it is missing ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add more slivers on `CustomScrollView`, when the viewport is bigger than slivers height, you will get the effect. Try adding SliverList or other sliver,

```dart
body: CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverAppBar(
      expandedHeight: 200,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        title: Text("title"),
      ),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 3333,
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

You can check [this video](https://youtu.be/YY-_yrZdjGc)

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to this.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) { return const MaterialApp( home: Scaffold( body: CustomScrollView(

    slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(
        expandedHeight: 200,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          title: Text("title"),
        ),
        expanded: true,
      ),
    ],
  ),
));
}}
```

Comment: expanded is not a parameter